# What is the simplest way to set up a BIRT report viewer for a xulrunner application?

Tags: reporting, xul, birt, xulrunner

I recently began using [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/) and have developed a report to use with my [xulrunner](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner) application.  What I haven't yet figured out is how I should deploy the viewer.  It seems like BIRT mostly targets Java applications, so there are instructions for deploying on J2EE, JBoss, and other technologies -- with which I am not familiar (but I'm not developing in Java anyway).

Reviewing [this article](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/07/26/deploying-birt.html) on deploying BIRT and reviewing the [deployment details](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/) on BIRT's web site, I'm not sure where to go.  I wasn't expecting to have to add some large Java dependency for the xulrunner application --is there no way I can drop an executable in with my xulrunner app, call it from my app, and pass it a report document?  (Or something else that would be simpler than learning and using J2EE, JBoss, tomcat?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that there is a genReport.bat file in the run-time somewhere that can generate reports from the command line.  This appears to be what I need, and [this article](http://digiassn.blogspot.com/2006/07/birt-birt-report-scheduling-without.html) describes it.

Answer (score 3):

(11/2014) I'm going to add:

- download Birt runtime from: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-4_3_0-201306131152/birt-runtime-4_3_0.zip
- extract somewhere and set a new Environment variable BIRT_HOME=path_to_where_you_extracted
- remember to add your database library into \ReportEngine\lib , (ex: jtds.jar)
- Open a console inside ReportEngine dir and run:
  `genReport.bat -f PDF -o  PATH/GENERATED_REPORTS/REPORT.pdf -F "PATH/TO/REPORT.rptdesign"`

And that's all what I needed to do